# Threefolds of general type with no holomorphic forms?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In relation to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318900/3-fold-of-general-type-homeomorphic-to-rational-3-fold), I would like to ask for  examples of (complex) threefolds of general type with no (nontrivial) holomorphic form.

Comment: Forms of some degree, or forms of all degrees?

Comment: Presumably there are examples that are quotients of general type 3fold complete intersections similar to the Godeaux surface.  Do you want examples that are simply connected?

Comment: @Jason Starr: no, that doesn't work. $\chi (\mathcal{O})$ is negative for a complete intersection threefold of general type, thus also for any quotient by a free action, while we want $\chi (\mathcal{O})=1$.

Comment: @Sasha: forms of all degrees $>0$.

Comment: @abx: Isn't it possible to cook up an example by taking the quotient of the product of three curves by a finite group action, an analogue of fake $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$?

Comment: Maybe a general pencil of Godeaux surfaces? . . .

Comment: @Sasha: Again this would have $\chi (\mathcal{O})<0$.

Comment: @abx: Sorry, but I don't understand why is $\chi(\mathcal{O}) < 0$? In the surface case this objection doesn't work, right?

Comment: For the pencil of Godeaux surfaces, it looks like the Reid -- Shepherd-Barron -- Tai criterion applies.  I will try to write up the details below . . .

Comment: @Sasha: $\chi (\mathcal{O})$ is negative for a curve, so for a product of $n$ curves it has the same sign as $(-1)^n$.

Comment: @abx: Sure, but when you take the quotient you can kill higher cohomology groups. At list this is what happens for fake quadrics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One simply connected example arises as the total space of a family of Godeaux surfaces over $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ with sufficiently positive discriminant.

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic different from $5$.  Let $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ be $\text{Proj}\ k[R,S]$.  Let $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ be $\text{Proj}\ k[T_0,T_1,T_2,T_3]$.  Let $e$ be a nonnegative integer.  Let $b_0,b_1,b_2,b_3 \in k[R,S]_e$ be a $4$-tuple of homogeneous polynomials of degree $e$ on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$.

**Hypothesis 1.** The integer $e$ is $\geq 3$.  Every zero in $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ of each polynomial $b_i$ is a simple zero, and there is no simultaneous zero of two or more of the polynomials $b_i,b_j$.

**Notation 2.** Denote by $f$ be the section of $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^*\mathcal{O}(e)\otimes \text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^3}^*\mathcal{O}(5)$, $$f = b_0 T_0^5 + b_1 T_1^5 + b_2 T_2^5 + b_3 T_3^5.$$  Denote by $Y$ be the zero scheme of $f$ as a hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^1_k\times_{\text{Spec}\ k} \mathbb{P}^3_k$.  For each $i=0,1,2,3$, denote by $p_i$ the $k$-point of $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ where $T_j$ vanishes for every $j\neq i$.  Also denote by $Y_i\subset Y$ the product $\text{Zero}(b_i)\times\{p_i\}$.  Finally, denote the restrictions of $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ and $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^3}$ to $Y$ as follows, $$\pi:Y\to \mathbb{P}^1_k, \ \ \rho:Y\to \mathbb{P}^3_k.$$

Let $\mu_5$ denote the group $k$-scheme of $5^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity in $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$.  Since $\text{char}(k)$ is not $5$, this is $k$-smooth.  Let $\mu_5$ act on $\mathbb{P}^1_k\times_{\text{Spec}\ k}\mathbb{P}^3_k$ as follows, $$\zeta \bullet([S_0,S_1],[T_0,T_1,T_2,T_3]) = ([S_0,S_1],[T_0,\zeta T_1, \zeta^2 T_2, \zeta^3 T_3]).$$  The polynomial $f$ is invariant for this action. Thus, there is an induced action on $Y$.

**Notation 3.** Denote the quotient of this $\mu_5$-action on $Y$ by $\nu:Y\to X'$.  Denote by $\phi:X\to X'$ any strong desingularization of $X'$ that is projective.

**Proposition 4.** The projective $k$-scheme $X$ is simply connected and of general type.  Moreover, for $r=1,2,3$, the only global section of $\Omega^r_{X/k}$ is the zero section.

This will be proved in stages.

**Lemma 5.**  The hypersurface $Y$ is smooth.  The singular locus of the projection $\pi$ equals $Y_0\cup Y_1\cup Y_2 \cup Y_3$.  The projection $\rho$ is smooth over $p_i$ for every $i=0,1,2,3$.  The dualizing sheaf of $Y$ equals the restriction of $\text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^1}^*\mathcal{O}(e-2)\otimes \text{pr}_{\mathbb{P}^3}^*\mathcal{O}(1)$.

**Proof.**  By the Jacobian criterion, the projection $\pi$ is smooth away from $\cup_i Y_i$.  The fiber of $\rho$ over $p_i$ is the zero scheme of $b_i$, and this is reduced (hence smooth) by hypothesis.  Thus, the projection morphism $\rho$ is smooth at every point of $\cup_i Y_i$.  For every point of $Y$, either $\pi$ or $\rho$ is smooth, and hence $Y$ is everywhere smooth.  The remaining computations are straightforward. **QED**

**Lemma 6.** The action of $\mu_5$ on $Y\setminus \cup_i Y_i$ is free.  For every point of $\cup_i Y_i$, the *age* (in the sense of Reid -- Shepherd-Barron -- Tai) is $> 1$.

**Proof.**  The fixed points of the action on $\mathbb{P}^3_k$ are the points $p_i$.  Since the projection $\rho$ is equivariant, every fixed point in $Y$ maps to $p_i$ for some $i$.  Thus, the fixed locus is contained in $\cup_i Y_i$.

Since the projection $\rho$ is étale at every point of $\cup_i Y_i$, the age of that fixed point in $Y$ equals the age of the image fixed point, say $p_i$, in $\mathbb{P}^3_k$.  By the choice of action of $\mu_5$ on $\mathbb{P}^3_k$, every eigenvalue that occurs in $T_{\mathbb{P}^3,p_i}$ has multiplicity $1$.  Moreover, since the fixed points are isolated, none of these eigenvalues equals $1$.  Thus, for each choice of primitive generator $\zeta$ of $\mu_5$, the eigenvalues $\zeta^a,\zeta^b,\zeta_c$ that occur have $0<a<b<c <5$, up to rearrangement.  Thus, the sum $a+b+c$ is at least $1+2+3=6$.  Therefore the age $\alpha(\mathbb{P}^3,p_i) = (a+b+c)/5$ is strictly larger than $1$. **QED**

**Lemma 7.** The $k$-scheme $X'$ is projective, normal, $\mathbb{Q}$-Gorenstein, has ample $\mathbb{Q}$-canonical divisor class, and has only terminal finite quotient singularities.  Finally, $X'$ is simply connected.  Thus, every projective desingularization $X$ of $X'$ is a simply connected, projective $3$-fold of general type.

**Proof.**  The only nontrivial claim is that $X'$ has only terminal singularities.  This follows by the Reid--Shepherd-Barron--Tai criterion and the computation of the age above. 
Since $Y$ is simply connected, also $X'$ is simply connected.
**QED**

Since the morphism $\pi$ is $\mu_5$-invariant, there is a unique $k$-morphism, $$\pi':X'\to \mathbb{P}^1_k,$$ such that $\pi'\circ \nu$ equals $\pi$.  By Lemma 3, the singular locus of $\pi'$ equals $X'_0\cup X'_1\cup X'_2 \cup X'_3$, for $X'_i:= \nu(Y_i)$.  Thus, the smooth locus of $\pi$ equals the open complement $U$ of $\cup_i X'_i$ in $X'$.  On $U$, the transitivity exact sequence of $\pi$ gives a short exact sequence, $$0 \to \pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/k}|_U \to \Omega_{U/k} \to \Omega_{\pi}|_U \to 0.$$  This induces a short exact sequence, $$0 \to \pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/k}\otimes\Omega_{\pi}|_U \to \Omega^2_{U/k} \to \Omega^2_{\pi}|_U \to 0.$$  This also induces an isomorphism, $$\Omega^3_{U/k} \cong \pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1/k}\otimes \Omega^2_{\pi}|_U.$$

**Lemma 8.**  For $r=1,2$, the only global section of $\Omega^r_\pi$ on $U$ is the zero section.

**Proof.**  These coherent sheaves are locally free sheaves on the smooth $k$-scheme $U$.  Every nonzero section on $U$ restricts to a nonzero section of the restriction on the generic fiber $F$ of $\pi$.  The restriction of $\Omega^r_\pi$ to the generic fiber $F$ equals $\Omega^r_{F/k(\mathbb{P}^1)}$. The generic fiber $F$ of $\pi$ is a Godeaux surface over $k(\mathbb{P}^1)$.  Thus, $\Omega^r_{F/k(\mathbb{P}^1)}$ has only the zero global section for $r=1$ and $r=2$.  **QED**

**Proof of Proposition 4.**  It only remains to prove that every global section of $\Omega^r_{X/k}$ is the zero section for $r=1,2,3$.  Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism over $U$, it suffices to prove that every global section of $\Omega^r_{U/k}$ is the zero section.

Since the global sections of $\Omega^r_\pi$ on $U$ are zero for $r>0$, the only possibility for a nonzero global section of $\Omega^r_{U/k}$ is a global section of $\pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1_k/k}$ with $r=1$.  Of course $\pi^*\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1_k/k}$ equals $\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-2)$.  Since $X'$ is normal and since $\cup_i X'_i$ consists of finitely many points, every global section of $\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-2)$ on $U$ is the restriction of a unique global section on all of $X'$ of $\pi^*\mathcal{O}(-2)$.  By the projection formula, every such global section is the zero global section. **QED**

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe the easiest way to find a good example is in complete intersections in weighted projective spaces.

Let us consider a 3-fold $X$ of the form of complete intersection $X=X_{d_1,\ldots, d_c}\subset\mathbb{P}(a_0, \ldots, a_n)$ with the following properties:

1. $n-c=3$, i.e. $\dim X=3$.
2. $\sum d_i=\sum a_j+1$, i.e., $\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)=\mathcal{O}_X(1)$.
3. $X$ has at most terminal singularities.

Note that such 3-fold $X$ satisfies that $h^1(\mathcal{O}_X)=h^2(\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ and $h^3(\mathcal{O}_X)=h^0(K_X)=h^0(\mathcal{O}_X(1))$. So in order to find examples you want, we just need to find such $3$-fold with $a_0>1$ (this is equivalent to $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X(1))=0$), and take a resolution.

There are many such $3$-folds with properties 1--3, the list is given by Iano-Fletcher in Section 15 of [1], where he classified all possible cases for $a_d\leq 100$ and $d\leq 2$. One interesting thing is that Iano-Fletcher's list is later proved to be a full classification of $3$-folds with properties 1--3 by Chen--Chen--Chen [2].
So we just check the list with to find $3$-fold with $a_0>1$.

Here I mention one of my favorite example: $X=X_{46}\subset\mathbb{P}(4,5,6,7,23)$. 
The reason why it is interesting is that for this $X$, $|mK_X|$ gives a birational map when $m\geq 27$, but  $|26K_X|$ is not birational. This is so far the only known example of 3-fold of general type with this property (that $|26K_X|$ is not birational).

References:
[1] A. R. Iano-Fletcher, Working with weighted complete intersections, Explicit
birational geometry of 3-folds. London Mathematical Society, Lecture Note
Series, 281. Cambridge University Press, Cambridge, 2000. 101–-173

[2] J-J. Chen, J.A. Chen, M. Chen, On quasismooth weighted complete intersections, J. Algebraic Geom. 20 (2011): 239--262.