# Topology of Brody hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be a Brody hyperbolic complex projective manifold with $\pi_1(M)=\{0\}$. Can $M$ be homeomorphic to $P\times S^2$ where $P$ is a manifold?

Comment: There is a conjecture that hyperbolic projective manifolds have $K_{X}$ ample. Such manifolds do satisfy topological restrictions; from the Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau and Miyaoka-Yau inequalities in dimension 2 and 3 respectively. For example they can be used to give restrictions on the Betti numbers and allow one to rule out being diffeomorphic more than half of the Fano $3$-folds https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318900/3-fold-of-general-type-homeomorphic-to-rational-3-fold. On the other hand, the conjecture suggests that there is not an example of what you ask for in the current literature.